Error ORA-01775: ejecutando bucle de cadena de sinónimos
Tengo un problema y es que cuando compilo mi paquete me manda el siguiente error:

Error: ORA-01775: ejecutando bucle de cadena de sinónimos


La cuestión aquí es que NO uso sinónimos ni he creado ni uno solo por lo que no se que verificar dentro de la base de datos que me esté ocasionando esto.

He verificado llamadas recursivas a funciones y procedimientos que sean cíclicos.
Que las tablas que se llaman existan.
Permisos (Grants).
Ajustes de llamadas a tablas con su respectivo esquema ESQUEMA.TABLENAME.
Ajustes de tipos con su esquema ESQUEMA.COLUMN%TYPE
Paquetes descompilados (todos ok)

Cualquier otra validación que conozcan y pueda hacer agradecería de su ayuda.

Solamente aparece ese error? no es más completo? Por que lo que pasa, es que A está apuntando a B y B apunta para A, entonces ese es el ciclo infinito. Por favor agrega detalles, de donde sucede este error.

Solo aparece ese error, no hay ningún ciclo como lo comentas.

El error describe un ciclo directamente de eso no hay duda. Quizás tu no usas manualmente los sinónimos, pero la BD detecta ese problema. Necesitas un [mre] para entender que sucede. Sino, tendrías que manualmente buscar todos los sinónimos de la base de datos y revisarlos.

Tendré que revisar, si el paquete hace llamados a otros procedimientos de otro paquete en otro esquema y este tiene ciclos puede afectar a la compilación de mi paquete que no deja compilar?

Esto último lo desconozco, quedaré al pendiente contigo si viene alguien que sepa mejor de este problema igual.

Va, agradezco tu ayuda.

Sin ver el código y sin un [mcve], creo que solo queda dirigirte a la documentación del error, para que, comprendiendo lo que allí dice, puedas inspeccionar por ti mismo.

La solución fué validar los enlaces a otra base de datos (DB LINKS) ya que esta accedía a otros paquetes que necesitaban de GRANTS a sus sinónimos.
Digamos que mi usuario de la base de datos DBPRUEBA1 es USERDB1, desde mi paquete accedía mediante un DBLINK a DBPRUEBA2 donde accedía a datos de una tabla (SELECT), al intentar obtenerlos mediante ese DBLINK desde DBPRUEBA1 y no tener los GRANTS necesarios para hacer la consulta me marcaba ese error de bucle además de que el GRANT debería tener el nombre del sinónimo consultado.

GRANT SELECT ON TABLE_SYNONYM TO DBLINKNAME@HOST

Espero que les sirva esta solución además de realizar las validaciones que están marcadas en la pregunta en caso de tener el mismo error.
